# Trying to loop through an array and keep last position remembered

Tags: javascript

I have a little assignment I can't manage to complete.

***Goal**
You have recently been assigned to a new amusement park’s center of analysis and supervision. Your mission is to estimate each day what the earnings will be for each ride that day. You start by looking at the roller coaster.

**Rules**
You notice that people like the roller coaster so much that as soon as they have finished a ride, they cannot help but go back for another one.
People queue up in front of the attraction
They can either be alone or in a group. When groups are in the queue, they necessarily want to ride together, without being separated.
People never overtake each other in the queue.
When there isn’t enough space in the attraction for the next group in the queue, the ride starts (so it is not always full).
As soon as the ride is finished, the groups that come out, go back into the queue in the same order.*

```
    var limited_number_of_seats_per_ride   = 3, //L
        limited_number_of_turns_per_ride   = 3, //C
        limited_number_of_groups_in_queue  = 4, //N
        number_of_person_per_group         = [3,1,1,2]; //P

   function earning_per_day(P,L,C,price){

      /**
      *
      * @P              {array}      number of person per group.
      * @L              {int}        limited number of seats per ride.
      * @C              {int}        limited number of times the ride goes per day.
      * @price          {int}        price per person per ride.
      *
      * @daily_earning {int}         estimated daily earnings.
      */

      var daily_earning = 0;
      var total_per_ride = 0;
      // calculates sum of the earning for each ride per day
      for (var j = 0; j < C; j++) {
        total_per_ride = 0;
        position_i = 0;
        // calculates the number of person on each ride
        for (var i = position_i; i < P.length; i++){
          while((total_per_ride + P[i+1]) < L){
            total_per_ride += P[i];
            console.log(i + ' total_per_ride = ' + total_per_ride);
          }
          position_i = i;
          console.log('position_i = ' + position_i);
        }
        daily_earning += total_per_ride;
        console.log('daily_earning ' + daily_earning);
      }
    }

    // calling
    earning_per_day(number_of_person_per_group, limited_number_of_seats_per_ride, limited_number_of_turns_per_ride, 1);
```

This is what I have so far. However, I have an idea I can't manage to put in place. Since the rules state that ***"that people like the roller coaster so much that as soon as they have finished a ride, they cannot help but go back for another one"***. I want to save the position of the loop at the moment it ends and restart the loop on that exact same position. Avoiding me to push and shift the element to the last positions of the array.

Can someone please give me a hint on how to proceed ?

Thank you very much !

Ryan

Comment: consider using a queue data structure. This will allow you to push new items into the queue and pop new ones out the front before processing them

Comment: @Lachlan Lindsay, ok, was not aware of this technique. Thank you, I will definitely look it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated little of your logic.

For continuously looping over `P` I have used increment index `position_i` as `position_i = (position_i + 1) % P.length;`.

There is no need for inner `for (var i = position_i; i < P.length; i++){`. Just updated `while(){...}`.

```js
var limited_number_of_seats_per_ride = 3, //L
  limited_number_of_turns_per_ride = 3, //C
  limited_number_of_groups_in_queue = 4, //N
  number_of_person_per_group = [3, 1, 1, 2]; //P

function earning_per_day(P, L, C, price) {

  /**
   *
   * @P              {array}      number of person per group.
   * @L              {int}        limited number of seats per ride.
   * @C              {int}        limited number of times the ride goes per day.
   * @price          {int}        price per person per ride.
   *
   * @daily_earning {int}         estimated daily earnings.
   */

  var daily_earning = 0;
  var position_i = 0;
  console.log('---daily_earning : ' + daily_earning + '---');

  // calculates sum of the earning for each ride per day
  for (var j = 0; j < C; j++) {
  console.log('---Ride ' + (j + 1) + '---');
    var total_per_ride = 0;
    // calculates the number of person on each ride
    // for (var i = position_i; i < P.length; i++){
    while ((total_per_ride + P[position_i]) <= L) {
      total_per_ride += P[position_i];    
      position_i = (position_i + 1) % P.length;
    }
    console.log('total_per_ride = ' + total_per_ride);
    console.log('New Start position_i = ' + position_i);
    // }
    daily_earning += total_per_ride;
    console.log('daily_earning ' + daily_earning);
  }
}

// calling
earning_per_day(number_of_person_per_group, limited_number_of_seats_per_ride, limited_number_of_turns_per_ride, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I see where I went wrong. I understand the logic except for one thing, why 

`position_i = (position_i + 1) % P.length` ? 

It's a use of the % operator I've thought of.

Comment: @GeorgesRyan `%` will give you `Modulus (Remainder)`. So `position_i = (position_i + 1) % P.length` will work as when `position_i ` is `0` then it will become `1` and so on. When `position_i ` is `3` then `(3+1)%4` will become `0`. So it will loop from `0` again.